# Content database size discrepancy/inconsistency - why?

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database

I'm trying to check a content database's size. I want to use Powershell, but the method I've found examples of online is giving me a result that is inconsistent with other ways of looking at the database.

If I do

```
$db = Get-SPContentDatabase | ? { $_.Name -eq $myDbName }
$dbSize = [Math]::Round(($db.DiskSizeRequired/1GB),2)
Write-Host $dbSize
```

I get 71.22 GB.

If I go to SQL Server Management Studio and look at the database properties through that, it tells me that the database is 83664.00 MB. But `83664 / 1024 = 81.703125` (or `83664 / 1000 = 83.664`), which is not the same either way.

But *then*, if I go to the filesystem and find the database file, it tells me it's..... **16 GB**.

Why the discrepancies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have blob storage configured by any chance? It might explain why your MDF file is smaller on disk.

`db.DiskSizeRequired` shows how large is database in terms of consumed spaced. This should include your total content size + log file size minus **unused space**.

Database size in SSMS shows how much space your content and logs take, plus **reserved space** that's not yet consumed.

If your SQL database's auto-growth setting is set to 10GB, then the database size will increase by 10GB, and at one point `DiskSizeRequired` might be significantly lower than what SSMS shows.

I can't explain a small MDF file size, but some guesses:

- blog storage
- wrong database file, maybe?
- Unlikely, but maybe there are file partitions created and it means some tables are stored in a different location.

Comment: Actually, it was the log. The log file was on a completely different drive. Filesystem content file size + log file size does equal SSMS reported size.  I'm guessing the 10 GB difference between SSMS vs. `DiskSizeRequired` does have to do with unused/reserved space.

Comment: Ah of course! That's so obvious now that I think about it. Logs are typically stored on a different drive.